# How can I add my app shortcut to notification panel

Tags: android

How can I add a button of my app or shortcut to the notification panel?

I researched it but unfortunately no results.

I want something like this picture below, as you can see some apps created their shortcuts in there (like Adm and windscribe)

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can achive that... I think that´s related to the ROM you have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create your own `Tile` and a `TileService` to handle the following action:

```
class CustomTileService: TileService(){

    override fun onClick() {
        super.onClick()
    }

    override fun onTileRemoved() {
        super.onTileRemoved()
    }

    override fun onTileAdded() {
        super.onTileAdded()
    }

    override fun onStartListening() {
        super.onStartListening()
    }

    override fun onStopListening() {
        super.onStopListening()
    }
}
```

And declare the correct permissions at the manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".CustomTileService"
    android:icon="@drawable/tile_icon"
    android:label="@string/tile_name"
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

You can find further information at Android docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/Tile

Comment: just also add (android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true") to service tag and it's done.

Comment: Use this guide for more details : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-quick-settings-tile-for-android--cms-30318