# how to make my app launch icon/button addable to android "shortcut center"

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, expo

Even if I call it "shortcut center". I'm not sure what's it's call. Basically what I want is to add a launching icon to the below menu. I don't know where to begin with.

My app is created with expo react native.
If it can't be done with react-native please point to any other example app using any language.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: as a 3rd party app, I can add *shazam* to my shortcut menu

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333691/how-can-i-add-my-app-shortcut-to-notification-panel) and [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/Tile).
sample project from [github](https://github.com/journaldev/journaldev/tree/master/Android/AndroidQuickSettingsTitle).
It's called android tiles under quicksettings.